# Codename one java ios app PROGUARD warnings trouble

Tags: java, maven, error-handling, codenameone, proguard

I'm writing IOS app using codename one project that I get from codename`s initializer cite.
At some point I have to use java.net, java.io and java.util packages.
But when I'm trying to build project, following warnings occurs:

[image]

"[INFO] ProGuard, version 7.2.0-beta2
[INFO] Reading input...
[INFO] Reading program jar [C:\Users\Kor\IdeaProjects\testapp\common\target\compliance-check.jar] (filtered)
[INFO] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Kor.m2\repository\com\codenameone\java-runtime\7.0.86\java-runtime-7.0.86.jar] (filtered)
[INFO] Reading library jar [C:\Users\Kor.m2\repository\com\codenameone\codenameone-core\7.0.117\codenameone-core-7.0.117.jar] (filtered)
[INFO] Initializing...
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.net.URL
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.net.URLConnection
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.util.Scanner
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.net.URL
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.net.URL
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.net.URLConnection
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.util.Scanner
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.util.Scanner
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.util.Scanner
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.net.URLConnection
[INFO] Warning: com.kor.testiosapp.forms.ResultsForm: can't find referenced class java.util.Scanner
[INFO] Warning: there were 11 unresolved references to classes or interfaces.
[INFO]          You may need to add missing library jars or update their versions.
[INFO]          If your code works fine without the missing classes, you can suppress
[INFO]          the warnings with '-dontwarn' options.
[INFO]          (https://www.guardsquare.com/proguard/manual/troubleshooting#unresolvedclass)
[INFO] java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first."

The manual to which link leads has brief description of problem cause and it's solution.
But I even can't find proguard config file to put necessary options.
I guess that config file lays somewhere in codename one libs and that`s the reason I can't find it.

I also read this part of manual: " For example, if ProGuard complains that it can't find a java.lang class, you have to make sure that you are specifying the run-time library of your platform. For JSE, these are typically packaged in lib/rt.jar (vm.jar for IBM's JVM, and classes.jar in MacOS X) or as of Java 9, jmods/java.base.jmod."

But that didn't help me either, as *I don't understand the point of the "make sure that you are specifying the run-time library of your platform" part.*

Comment: Please don't post images of text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is there to indicate that you are using classes that are unsupported by the Codename One API such as `Scanner`.  You can review the supported classes in the JavaDoc [here](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/).

Classes like `Scanner` are mostly about user command line input which isn't relevant when running on a device.

Comment: Now I see. But what if I need some extra classes or packages ? How to properly add them to my project ?
For example, in this project I need to send GET request to certain endpoint and map the response. And packages that Codename one supports can`t fulfill my needs.

Comment: You can include some jars but that's problematic see: https://help.codenameone.com/en-us/article/can-i-use-any-jar-1uav2ka/
We have multiple APIs for networking and REST. E.g. the [Rest](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/terse-rest-api.html) API is [relatively easy to use](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/new-rest-calls.html). Especially with [properties](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/properties-are-amazing.html) e.g. [this](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/io/rest/RequestBuilder.html#body-com.codename1.properties.PropertyBusinessObject-).